# influxdb - selection using bit testing?

Tags: influxdb, bitmask

Is there a way in InfluxDB to use bitwise operators in a search query? For example, if I want to find all points where the 2nd bit of a tag or field value is set, I'd like to be able to do something like:

SELECT * FROM measurement WHERE tag_name & (1<<1) = true

or

SELECT * FROM measurement WHERE (tag_name >> 1) & 1 = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Can I find all the points which has the 2nd bit set in a `tag` or `field`?

**A:** Not possible for `tag` because its value is always `string` type.

Yes for `Field` value **but** performing `filtering` on it can have performance impact as `field` is not indexed. That is, every `SELECT` query is a full table scan.

The `bitwise operators` are only introduced in influx `1.3.x`, so if you're using an earlier release then you won't be able to do the following.

Assuming you have the following `dataset`.

```
> show field keys from measurement_abcd
name: measurement_abcd
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
value    integer

> select * from measurement_abcd
name: measurement_abcd
time                tag1 value
----                ---- -----
1434086562000000000      2
1434087562000000000      3
1434088562000000000      4
1434089562000000000 abc  5
1434089562000000000      5
```

You can retrieve rows that has the 2nd bit set in field `value` by **doing**;

`SELECT * FROM measurement_abcd WHERE "value" | 2 = "value"`

This will give you the following **output**;

```
> SELECT * FROM measurement_abcd WHERE "value" | 2 = "value"
name: measurement_abcd
time                tag1 value
----                ---- -----
1434086562000000000      2
1434087562000000000      3
```

Something worth noting is that influx's Bitwise operators only works on `boolean` and `integer`. It won't work on float.

**Reference:**
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/query_language/math_operators/#bitwise-and

Use the following data to replicate the experiment above:

> curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=stackoverflow1'
>   --data-binary 'measurement_abcd value=2i 1434086562000000000'
>
> curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=stackoverflow1' --data-binary 'measurement_abcd value=3i 1434087562000000000'
>
> curl -i -XPOST
>   'http://localhost:8086/write?db=stackoverflow1' --data-binary
>   'measurement_abcd value=4i 1434088562000000000'
>
> curl -i -XPOST
>   'http://localhost:8086/write?db=stackoverflow1' --data-binary
>   'measurement_abcd value=5i 1434089562000000000'

Comment: Does InfluxDB has the support for Shift operators ?

Comment: @Vignesh Raja https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/math_operators/#solution